# Find the limit of $\sqrt{x^2+x-1} +x$ as $x\to-\infty$

Tags: calculus, limits, radicals

Find the limit of $\sqrt{x^2+x-1} +x$ as $x\to-\infty$.

My solution:

**multiplying by:** $\displaystyle\frac{\sqrt{x^2+x-1}-x}{\sqrt{x^2+x-1}-x}$

**Which gives us:** $\displaystyle\frac{x-1}{\sqrt{x^2+x-1}-x}$

**dividing by** $\sqrt{x^2}$ gives:

$\displaystyle \frac{1}{\sqrt{1}-1}$

**which equals** $1/0$

However, I double checked my answers, and this does not seem to be correct, am I making a mistake (perhaps when I take the $\sqrt{1}$ in the denominator of the last step?

Answer (score 4):

I don't really like negative numbers, they are so *negative*. Let $x=-p$ where $p$ is positive. We want 
$$\lim_{p\to\infty}\left(\sqrt{p^2-p-1}-p\right).$$
A mistake is now much less likely.

Comment: I don't see why/how you changed the sign of infinity from negative to positive

Comment: Because $x\to-\infty$. So since $p=-x$, we get that $p\to\infty$.

Comment: That makes sense. 

When we get the final limit of the function as p -> infinity, would we then have to switch back and thus multiply the limit by $(-1)$?

Comment: The limit is **unchanged**. After the rationalization, we have $\frac{-p-1}{\sqrt{p^2-p-1}+\sqrt{p}}$. Dividing top and bottom by $p$, we get that the new top approaches $-1$, and the new bottom approaches $2$, so the whole thing has limit $-\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

$\sqrt{x^2}$ is a positive number and since we are taking the limit as $x\to -\infty$, we have $\sqrt{x^2} = -x$. Your limit will be negative since $x^2>x^2+x-1$ as $x\to-\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake at this step:

> **dividing by** $\sqrt{x^2}$ gives: $\displaystyle \frac{1}{\sqrt{1}-1}$

**Since $x\to -\infty$, then $\sqrt{x^2}=-x$. So $\frac{x-1}{\sqrt{x^2+x-1}-x}=\frac{-1+\frac 1x}{\sqrt{1+\frac 1x-\frac{1}{x^2}}+1}.$
Take careful!**

Answer (score 0):

Writing $-\dfrac1h=x,$

$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}(\sqrt{x^2+x-1}+x)=\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{\sqrt{1+h-h^2}-1}h$$

$$=\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{(1+h-h^2)-1}{h(\sqrt{1+h-h^2}+1)}$$

$$=\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{1-h}{\sqrt{1+h-h^2}+1}=?$$